# How to create ios LocalNotification from array of dates?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have an array of dates

```
NSArray *datesArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"2014-09-14 00:00:00",@"2014-08-21 07:12:36",@"2014-08-14 00:00:00",@"2014-07-14 00:00:00",@"2014-06-14 00:00:00",@"2015-01-01 10:00:00",@"2014-06-14 00:00:00",@"2014-05-14 11:24:15", nil];
```

now i want to fire one day before the date available in array
How to implement it?

I was trying this

```
    NSDateFormatter *Formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Formatter1 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];
    [Formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [Formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSDate *date1 =[NSDate date];
    NSString *string =[Formatter1 stringFromDate:date1];
    NSLog(@"sring %@",string);
    NSDate *todaydate =[Formatter1 dateFromString:string];
    NSLog(@"2day date is %@",todaydate);

for (int i=0;i<datesArray.count;i++)
{
    NSDate *_date =[Formatter1 dateFromString:[datesArray objectAtIndex:i ]];
    NSLog(@"date is %@",_date);
    if(_date == todaydate){
        localNotif.fireDate = _date;
        localNotif.alertBody = @"festival";
        localNotif.alertAction=@"Show me";
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    }
```

Comment: A small note on code style - change `Formatter1` to `formatter1`. Classes should start with uppercase letters and variables with lowercase letters. This will improve your code's clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract a day by using the `NSCalendar` functions, specifically `dateByAddingComponents`

```
NSArray *datesArray = @[@"2014-09-14 00:00:00",@"2014-08-21 07:12:36",@"2014-08-14 00:00:00",@"2014-07-14 00:00:00",@"2014-06-14 00:00:00",@"2015-01-01 10:00:00",@"2014-06-14 00:00:00",@"2014-05-14 11:24:15"];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:-1];

NSDateFormatter *Formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[Formatter1 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];
[Formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[Formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

[datesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.fireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[Formatter1 dateFromString:obj] options:0];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"festival";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}];
```

W

Comment: :Thank you for answer..whenever i run the app local notification pop up..also it will pop up exact 1 day earlier?

Comment: Indeed. Look into cancelling notifications, you can do this by using `cancelAllLocalNotifications`. If you have a reference to the notification you can cancel a specific one: `cancelLocalNotification:`. You can get the reference by using `scheduledLocalNotifications` - This will let you know all the notifications that have been scheduled. You could even check if there is an existing notification with the same date before you add another one using this method.

Comment: fine thank u..one more question..if above datesarray are the json object and i want to pull it from json service for UILocalNotification

Comment: `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.jsonData options:0 error:NULL]` will return a dictionary that you can call `objectForKey:` on.

Comment: ohk u mean i parse json and then it can dynamically communicate with UILocalNotification giving notification for particular events in the specified dated for that events.So parsing can be done in applicationDidEnterBackground method because i want notification when app is in background state.

Comment: Make sure your app is registered for background modes. If not you will not get much processing time in did enter background.